# Resize background image of canvas - Fabricjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabricjs to play around with canvas, and loading a image into it via javascript.

I have a function that resizes the canvas to make it responsive and as such would like to resize the background image that was loaded to fit the canvas too but keep the aspect ratio.

I have not found examples currently that meet my criteria and am hoping someone can assist.

Javascript

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('drawing_layer');
 var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
                canvas.setBackgroundImage(img.src, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
                    originX: 'left',
                    originY: 'top',
                    left: 0,
                    top: 0
                });

// initially sets width of canvas to fit the image
                canvas.setDimensions({
                    width: img.width,
                    height: img.height
                });
            };
// below is a call to function that resizes the canvas
resizeCanvas();

//sets listener to resize event
            window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
```

Comment: can i have jsfiddle for this ?

Comment: Aeseir, I am facing same issue. Di you find the solution for it?

Comment: yea, just posted the answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution in Angular 2+.

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
      resizeCanvas(event?: any) {
        const width: number = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
        const height: number = (window.innerHeight > 0) ? window.innerHeight : screen.height;
        const widthn: number = width * 0.7;
        const heightn: number = height - 100;
        canvas.setDimensions({
          width: widthn,
          height: heightn,
        });
      }
```

Comment: what do 0.7 and 100 represent?

Comment: look at it in context of whole, width gets reduced to 70% of size, while height gets reduced by 100px

Answer (score 5):

Your resizeCanvas() should look like:

```
resizeCanvas(width, height) {
  canvas.backgroundImage.scaleToWidth(width);
  canvas.backgroundImage.scaleToHeight(height);
  canvas.setDimensions({width: width, height: height});
  canvas.renderAll();
}
```

And you should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set background image by preserving the aspect ratio of the image and also set it in the center of the canvas.

```
const setBackgroundFromDataUrl = (dataUrl, options = {}) => {
  if (!dataUrl) { return true; }

  let img = new Image();
  img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
  img.onload = () => {

   // maxWidth // Max width of the canvas
   // maxHeight //Max height of canvas

    let imgWidth = img.width; // Current image width
    let imgHeight = img.height; // Current image height

    let widthAspectRatio = maxWidth / imgWidth;
    let heightAspectRatio = maxHeight / imgHeight;

    let finalAspectRatio = Math.min(widthAspectRatio, heightAspectRatio)

    let finalHeight = imgHeight * finalAspectRatio;
    let finalWidth = imgWidth * finalAspectRatio;

    let imgTop = 0;
    if (maxHeight > finalHeight) {
      imgTop = (Math.round(maxHeight) - Math.round(finalHeight)) / 2;
    }

    let imgLeft = 0;
    if (maxWidth > finalWidth) {
      imgLeft = (Math.round(maxWidth) - Math.round(finalWidth)) / 2;
    }

    let nsgImage = new fabric.Image(img).scale(finalAspectRatio);
    nsgImage.set({ left: imgLeft, top: imgTop });

    canvas.setBackgroundImage(nsgImage, () => canvas.renderAll());

  }

  img.src = dataUrl;

};
```